# IFTTT Maker Channel - Send POST Request to ipv6 adress

Tags: automation, home-automation, openhab, ifttt

Is ist possible to send POST requests to ipv6 addresses using the ifttt.com service?

I found the maker channel but it doesn't seem to work (with ipv6 addresses).

Here the request I want to send to my openhab system:
POST 
http://[xyyx:yxy:yxy:yxyx:yxyx:yxyx:yxyx:yxyx]:8080/rest/items/Kueche
Content-Type: text/plain
Body: TOGGLE

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, want to use Maker with IPv6 address. Don't seems to work, neither passing a domain that only resolves to an IPv6 address.

I have done a workaround, using Google App Engine (it has IPv6 support) as a proxy for my IFTTT Maker requests.

The code is pretty ugly, just a POC:
https://gist.github.com/6f9e67fe47c67eca46655b8033bcf862

In the Maker "that" is set the URL like this:

`https://miappid.appspot.com/?query=data&ipv6=http://home.duckdns.org`

The app deployed in GAE take the parameters of the query (except ipv6), content-type header and body, and create a new request to the addres specified in the ipv6 param.